# Aggregate/group data frame slice rows by sequential indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I performed a slice on an original data frame using a Boolean condition, and I'd like to aggregate rows in the returned slice in groups based on sequential indices.

Say I'm returned indices of:

```
1   x   y   z
2   x   y   z
3   x   y   z
7   x   y   z
11  x   y   z
12  x   y   z
13  x   y   z
```

I'm trying to create a list of errors that I find in the data frame based on a series of Boolean conditions, and only return one error per group of sequential indices with start index, stop index, and a string with the error description.

So what I'd like to see is a group of indices 1 to 3, then 7, then a group of 11 to 13

```
1    3    <error string>
7    7    <error string>
11   13   <error string>
```

I could loop through the slices and break everything up as I go, but is there a better way to do what I'd like to achieve?

Comment: This is confusing as worded, where does 'error string' exist in your data frame? What are the conditions that would cause you to start at one index and stop at another? Thanks in advance for clarifying...

Comment: I figured I was being a little confusing... <error string> is just a place holder for a string I'll associate with the row describing the error associated with it. Essentially what I'm trying to do is slice a given data frame on some boolean conditions, then group the resulting rows if their indices are continuous, thus allowing myself to report only one error if a bunch of consecutive rows have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried `.groupby` on the indices or whatever you are trying to "slice"? Typically it's possible / easiest to run these sorts of calculations based on group by objects, and backing up to indexes (`.iloc`) in the original DataFrame if needed.